# Matched route rule is using default module isntead of the specified module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

For some odd reason, the default module and action are being used when a defined route is being matched in my Symfony project.  I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this as I've been banging my head on my desk for a while trying to figure it out.

**route.yml**

```
supplies_similar:
 url: supply/similar/:id/page/:page
 param { module: supplySimilar, action: index }
```

**view code**

```
 <?php echo link_to($page, '@supplies_similar?id='.$id.'&page='.$page); ?>
```

**log message**

> Match route "supplies_similar" (/supply/similar/:id/page/:page) for /supply/similar/2087641/page/2 with parameters array ( **'module' => 'default', 'action' => 'index'**, 'id' => '2087641', 'page' => '2',)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your indentation in your routing.yml and don't forget the colon after "param":

```
supplies_similar:
 url: supply/similar/:id/page/:page
 param: { module: supplySimilar, action: index }
```

Comment: Oh my word, I knew...just knew it was going to be something so simple.  Indeed, I was missing the colon and I just never spotted it.  Thanks!